# How to correctly run protractor tests? ng e2e equal to protractor... something

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

Hey I have quick question,  I've installed protractor, and I have this basic e2e folder in my Angular project.
If I use command "ng e2e", will it build and run my tests inside e2e folder **using** protractor framework or will it run it **without** protractor? It's very important for me, I want to run it using protractor. Can I do it with ng command? Thank you If you will answer this :)

Comment: You could check in your `angular.json` whether your e2e project is using protractor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ng e2e`, then you are already using `protractor` by default. It because `protractor` is a built-in E2E testing framework for Angular.

If you are already installed `protractor` in global. (`npm install -g protractor`) The `ng e2e` command also execute the `protractor` within your Angular project. It's not your global's protractor.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @blackko2 If you think this is your answer, you can mark it as answer.